# Fetch column from table and store in an array

Tags: php

Am new to PHP. I tried to fetch the elements from a table but it is getting stored as a single element in an array. I want each element in the column to be a separate element in the array.. Someone please help me with this..

```
$sql="select name from item_details";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$sql)
echo "Query Failed".mysql_error();
while($arr=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo $arr[0];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Dont use mysql_* functions any more.Use mysqli_* or pdo

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get an  **associative array** of column names. Like so:

```
$sql="select name from item_details";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$sql)
echo "Query Failed".mysql_error();
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

For future reference, you can always dump the array to see how it looks and get a look at its values. For example:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
var_dump($rows);// this will output the array and all its values nice and pretty.
```

### Also, stay away from mysql_* functions.

As mentioned in the comments, you might want to ditch `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. You might want to look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or an ORM like [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="select name from item_details";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$sql)
echo "Query Failed".mysql_error();

while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $arr['id']; //I assume a id column exists in item_details table
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What you have prescribed is wat happening to me... I dnt want to happen lik tat.. Wen i fetch a column from table its getting stored as a[0]... But i want each record in tat column to be stored as a[0],a[1],etc...

Comment: just stored them into another array. can I have an example of the result array